# deployment issue with fuel cms 1.4

Tags: fuelcms

i have installed and implemented a project in **fuel cms 1.4 with CI 3** (in my local machine)working well but i am getting issues while i copy pestled the folder to an Linux server it is giving error as follow

**Message:**

```
require_once(/sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/application/../../fuel/modules/fuel/models/base_module_model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: models/Home_banners.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/application/models/Home_banners.php
Line: 2
Function: _error_handler

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/application/models/Home_banners.php
Line: 2
Function: require_once

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/modules/fuel/core/Loader.php
Line: 237
Function: model

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/modules/fuel/core/Loader.php
Line: 262
Function: model

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/modules/fuel/core/Loader.php
Line: 224
Function: models

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/fuel/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 19
Function: model

File: /sambashare/htdocs/myproject/index.php
Line: 365
Function: require_once
```

> i fixed all known configuration an found that the actual file name is
>   Base_module_model.php in folder  so capitalization of first character
>   is causing the error .

what can i do for it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That file name should be capitalized in 1.4.**
http://forum.getfuelcms.com/discussion/2725/deployment-issue-with-fuel-cms-3#Item_4